# Node.js returns a blank html file to client

Tags: html, node.js, client-server, client, server

I'm new to node.js and have found a simple tutorial to set up a simple node.js server. I'm trying to render a html page on the client side, I do get the file, which I can see in the console, but the browser shows an empty page? This is my server.js file:

```
var http = require('http'); 
var url = require('url');                                                       
var fs = require('fs');                                 

var server = http.createServer(function(request, response){                     
    console.log('Connection');  
    var path = url.parse(request.url).pathname; 

switch(path){                                                               
    case'/':
        response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});             
        response.write('Hello World');                                      
        break;
    case '/socket.html':
        fs.readFile(__dirname + path, function(error, data){                
            if (error){                                                     
                response.writeHead(404);
                response.write("Oops, this doesn't exist! - 404");          
            }
            else {                                                          
                response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});     
                response.write(data, "utf8");
                console.log('Connection working!');
            }
        });
        break;
    default:
        response.writeHead(404);
        response.write("Oops, this doesn't exist - 404");                   
        break;
}
    response.end();                                                             
});

server.listen(8001);
```

Here is my simple html file socket.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <h1>This is the socket.html file</h1>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

And my response in the browser:

[image: Browser response]

I double-checked that I use 'url' and 'fs' modules correct, which I think I do? Can anybody help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fs.readfile` is asynchronous and will return the file contents after you've called `response.end()`.

Here is a quick fix. Hope it works.
I moved `response.end()` into the `fs.readFile` callback.

```
var http = require('http');
var url = require('url');
var fs = require('fs');

var server = http.createServer(function(request, response){
    console.log('Connection');  
    var path = url.parse(request.url).pathname; 

    switch(path){
        case'/':
            response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
            response.write('Hello World');
            response.end();
            break;
        case '/socket.html':
            fs.readFile(__dirname + path, function(error, data){
                if (error){
                    response.writeHead(404);
                    response.write("Oops, this doesn't exist! - 404");
                }
                else {
                    response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});
                    response.write(data, "utf8");
                    console.log('Connection working!');
                }
                response.end();
            });
            break;
        default:
            response.writeHead(404);
            response.write("Oops, this doesn't exist - 404");
            response.end();
            break;
    }
});

server.listen(8001);
```

Comment: Moving ´response.end()´ give me this error in console.log:
´GET http://localhost:8001/socket.html net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED´

Comment: That should not be caused by this. Are you saying you get that in the console of the server?

Comment: I moved `response.end()` in to the default and now it works! But logically I don't understand exactly why. If I the first 'case' is true, dont I still need a `response.end()`?

Comment: `response.end` is needed, unless it's called for you by for example piping a stream to `response`. But you're not doing that, so you are required to call `response.end`. In my "fix" above, I moved `response.end` into all the cases, not just the `default` case. Did you do that?

Comment: Good. However, I would suggest using some kind of router, for example [express](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express). Express can even serve static files for you [out of the box](http://expressjs.com/guide/using-middleware.html#middleware.built-in).

Comment: I did consider that. But the goal is to create a simple node.js server using socket.io, so I can connect the an Arduino Yun and control it through a browser.